# Rails Getting first nested resource of parent resource that matches boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource (user_answer) that references a **parent** resource (multiple_choice_question). Each User can attempt a multiple_choice_question as many times as they want, and the system saves every user_answer on click.

However, I want to be able to show the user how many unique questions they got right on the very first submission of user_answer.

Eg; Of 100 questions, the user answered 33 right on their first try. (based off .first or created_at, time based)

I wrote this query, but it's not correct. Not sure how to make it more specific for what is needed.

`@correct_on_first_attempt = @user.user_answers.where(:is_correct_answer => true).distinct.count(:multiple_choice_question_id).first`

UserAnswer Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_answers
#
#  id                          :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  user_id                     :integer
#  multiple_choice_question_id :integer
#  selected_answer             :text
#  is_correct_answer           :boolean
#  created_at                  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                  :datetime         not null
#
class UserAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :multiple_choice_question
end
```

MultipleChoiceQuestion Model

```
class MultipleChoiceQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :user, presence: true

has_many :user_answers
has_many :users, through: :user_answers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, firstly, I think you're putting `.first` at the end, when it isn't really required. I think removing that will fix the bug you're facing. Adding the `.first` doesn't really fetch the first result of each set of entries. It tries to fetch the "first" result out of an integer, which isn't really possible.

Secondly, as it stands, your query: `@correct_on_first_attempt = @user.user_answers.where(:is_correct_answer => true).distinct.count(:multiple_choice_question_id)` tries to find the total number of questions the user has answered correctly so far, while not having any condition on the first attempt or not.

If you want to find out whether the user was able to solve it in their first attempt or not is a slightly harder solution through SQL, because you need to find the earliest answer provided by the user for every question.

Depending on your database, there are multiple solutions that will work. In each case, I'd recommend writing the SQL query yourself, and executing it, rather than using Rails' helper functions, because ActiveRecord doesn't give enough versatility for your use-case.

Example SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT multiple_choice_question_id) FROM
  (
    SELECT multiple_choice_question_id,
           user_id,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
             PARTITION BY multiple_choice_question_id
             ORDER BY created_at
           ) AS rn
    FROM user_answers
    WHERE user_id = 4
    AND is_correct_answer = TRUE
  )
  WHERE rn = 1
```

You'll have to test this once; I haven't checked it.

Edit: A more Rails-ey solution:

```
distinct_question_ids = @user.user_answers.
  where(is_correct_answer: true).
  distinct.pluck(:multiple_choice_question_id)

@correct_on_first_attempt = distinct_question_ids.select { |qid|
  @user.user_answers.
    where(multiple_choice_question_id: qid).first.is_correct_answer
}.count
```

This isn't a good solution because it actually makes many SQL queries rather than just one like the previous solution, but it may be easier to understand.

Comment: Is it not possible through AR at all? I'm still relatievly new to rails and am not sure how to put or handle PostgreSQL queries - no idea where to put them

Comment: I've added an edit. That's probably the easiest way to go through ActiveRecord.

Comment: If you want to run a query, the process is quite simple: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)`